# Transformation of inequality

Tags: inequality

Assume
$$
\widehat{t}= \frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2}   ~~~~~~\widehat{T}= \frac{1-e^{-2T}}{2}
$$
and, $U(t)$ is a function for $t\ge 0$. $T$ is a positive constant. If I have a inequality 
$$
U(\widehat t) \ge \frac{e^{-2\widehat t}}{2(\widehat T - \widehat t)}   ~~~\text{when $\widehat t <\widehat T $}
$$
How can I get a inequality only contain $U(t) , t ,T$ , I mean it  like
$$
U(t)\ge f(t,T)   ~~~~\text{when  $t< T$}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi \, : \, t \in \mathbb{R} \, \mapsto \, \displaystyle \frac{1 - e^{-2t}}{2}$.

$\varphi$ is *one-to-one and onto*.

It is also (strictly) increasing and sends $\mathbb{R}$ onto $]-\infty, 1/2[$. As a result, an inequality of the form:

$$ \forall t, T \in \mathbb{R}, \, \varphi(t) < \varphi(T) \; \Rightarrow \, U\big( \varphi(t) \big) \geq g\big( \varphi(t), \varphi(T) \big) $$

transforms into:

$$ \forall s, S \in ]-\infty, 1/2[, \; s < S \; \Rightarrow \; U(s) \geq g(s,S). $$

Comment: Thanks, but $t$ can be any value of $\mathbb R$ ,  your $s$ can't be so.

Comment: @lanse7pty : Indeed, when $t$ describes the real line $\mathbb{R}$, $s = \varphi(t)$ is in $]-\infty, 1/2[$. In other words, the inequality $U(s) \geq g(s,S)$ holds but $s$ and $S$ cannot take any value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so , $U( t) \ge \frac{e^{-2  t}}{2( T -   t)}$  ?

Comment: Yes, as long as $t$ and $T$ are in $]-\infty,1/2[$, with $t < T$.

Comment: if $T> \frac{1}{2}$ , how to deal it ? In fact , $T$ and $\widehat T$ are constant.

Comment: You can check if the inequality still holds. The inequality
$$ U(\hat{t}) \geq \frac{e^{-2\hat{t}}}{2(\hat{T} - \hat{t})} $$
only tells you that
$$ U(t) \geq \frac{e^{-2t}}{2(T-t)} $$ 
holds for $T<1/2$ because $\hat{T} = (1-e^{-2T})/2 < 1/2$.

Comment: No, $T$ can be great than $\frac{1}{2}$.  Only $\widehat T < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: If you want to replace $\hat{T}$ with $T$ in your inequality, $T$ cannot be greater than $1/2$ (strictly).